# How to get user info after logging in with vue.js in “Vuexy Admin Dashboard Template”

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I need help to get information from the user after logging. in Vuexy Vuejs Admin Dashboard Template. With the current code, it now uses fake information.

please guide me.

```js
// axios
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers:{
    common:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    }
  }
})
```

Using the following code, we read the user name from the fake database. activeUserInfo.displayName

```js
//ProfileDropDown.vue
<template>
  <div class="text-right leading-tight hidden sm:block">
    <p class="font-semibold">{{ activeUserInfo.displayName }}</p>
    <small>Available</small>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeUserInfo () {
      return this.$store.state.AppActiveUser
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally, the user's fake name is returned from here. displayName: "Mary Adams",

```js
//state.js

const userDefaults = {
  uid         : 0, 
  displayName : "Mary Adams",
  status      : 'online',
  userRole    : 'admin'
}

const getters = {
  // get_user : response.data.userInfo
}

const userInfoLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) || {}

// Set default values for active-user
// More data can be added by auth provider or other plugins/packages
const getUserInfo = () => {
  const userInfo = {}

  // Update property in user
  Object.keys(userDefaults).forEach((key) => {
    // If property is defined in localStorage => Use that
    userInfo[key] = userInfoLocalStorage[key] ?  userInfoLocalStorage[key] : userDefaults[key]
  })

  // Include properties from localStorage
  Object.keys(userInfoLocalStorage).forEach((key) => {
    if (userInfo[key] === undefined && userInfoLocalStorage[key] !== null) userInfo[key] = userInfoLocalStorage[key]
  })

  return userInfo
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////
// State
// /////////////////////////////////////////////

const state = {
  AppActiveUser           : getUserInfo(),
  windowWidth: null
}

export default state
```

One of the professors said that this code will work, but since I am a beginner, I do not know what to do.

```js
you can simoly write method and call in in created hook.

//ProfileDropDown.vue
<template>
  <div class="text-right leading-tight hidden sm:block">
    <p class="font-semibold">{{ activeUserInfo.displayName }}</p>
    <small>Available</small>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
       activeUserInfo: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserInfo () {
      try {
           const res = await (write get request with axios to api)
           this.activeUserInfo = (object from res)
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  },
  async created() {
     await this.getUserInfo();
  }
}
</script>
If you want get data with store, you can use axios in state.js

...
const getUserInfo = () => {
  const userInfo = {}

  try {
      const res = await (write get request with axios to api)
      userInfo = (object from res)
  } catch (e) {}

  return userInfo
}
...
```

I received this error after npm run watch.

```js
  83 |     async getUserInfo () {
  84 |       try {
> 85 |            const res = await (write get request with axios to api)
     |                                     ^
  86 |            this.activeUserInfo = (object from res)
  87 |         } catch (e) {}
  88 |       },
```

And now I do not know how to fix the following error? Please, please give a real example so that I can just edit the code and the program will work. Thank you

Comment: You can find some example of use axios library in the documentation  here https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html
Here we are helping to fix code and not writing code from scratch, so we need to see the code that you tried and doesn't work.
you can read the documentation and replace your professor's comments with the necessary code.